# Under what conditions does $Ax = Bx$ imply $A = B$?

Tags: matrices

Let's suppose $x$ is the fixed vector with all entries being $1$ of an $n$ dimensional vector space $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $A,B \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}.$

If $Ax = Bx,$ then does $A = B$? If not, under what conditions does this hold?

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be a nonzero complex matrix such that $Mx = 0$, i.e. $x \in \operatorname{Ker}(M)$, then for every complex matrix $C$ it follows that $$(M+C)x = Cx$$ but $ M + C \not= C$

Comment: Okay, but in such a case, is $M$ singular? Because as I said, I'm inviting people to add the conditions under which $A = B.$ What if you were to also require that $M$ was non-singular?